# Не получается вызвать getter из другого класса (null) JAVA

Tags: java, null, getter

Всем привет. Как ни бьюсь, не получается понять суть геттера. Помогите пожалуйста.
На простом примере...
Есть два класса

Первый

```
public class Testoviy {
private String pass;
public void main (String[] args) {
    pass = "lol";
}
public String getPass(){
    return pass;
}}
```

Второй

```
public class Newclass {
Testoviy hello = new Testoviy();

public void lol() {
    String lol = hello.getPass();
    System.out.println(lol);
}}
```

Соответственно, хочу вывести значение переменной pass из первого класса, но у меня всегда Null

Comment: Первой строкой в метод `lol() ` добавьте `hello.main(); ` и будет вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо большое...Все никак и не мог понять, как же задействовать мейн

Comment: На всякий случай напишу... Ваш метод `main(String...)` похож на точку входа, но таковым не является, т.к. не есть `static`. Возможно, так и задумано, но нигде не используемые аргументы наталкивают на мысль, что таки очепятка)

Comment: Спасибо. Да, опечатка) Просто быстрый пример. У меня тут более сложный код, а тут я просто для примера начеркал два класса, чтобы понять как достать pass. Все получилось

Answer (score 1):

Рекомедую прочитать про принципы ООП и в частности обратить внимание на инкапсуляцию.
Ваш код не совсем корректен. Вы можете использовать операторы `{...}` для динамической инициализации, либо инициализировать переменные сразу же при объявлении  значений переменный. А вы инициализируете их внутри метода main()
Посмотрите на следующий код:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
   Test test = new Test();
   System.out.println(test);
  }
}

class Test {
  private String field = "this is test text";
  public void getField() {
   return field;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас метод

```
public void main (String[] args) {
    pass = "lol";
}
```

инициализирует поле `private String pass;`. Но этот метод вы никогда не вызываете, поэтому инициализации и не происходит.

Не совсем понятно, каким образом вы вызываете метод `lol()`, но прежде чем он вам что-то напечатает, должен отработать метод `main`, который и инициализирует `pass`.